# ical made with php won't show up in google calendar

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

I'm trying to create an ical from a calendar I created, both using PHP.

Cal url: https://www.gamingonlinux.com/index.php?module=calendar&view=ical

I've used a validator, and it claims it's valid, but no events show up in google calendar when I added it in to test.

Any thoughts on what my error is?

This is the code to make the ical:

```
// the iCal date format. Note the Z on the end indicates a UTC timestamp.
define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis\Z');

// max line length is 75 chars. New line is \\n

$output = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nPRODID:-//Gaming On Linux//Release Calendar//EN\r\n";

$db->pquery("SELECT `id`, `date`, `name`, `comment`, `link`, `best_guess` FROM `calendar` WHERE YEAR(date) = $year AND `approved` = 1 ORDER BY `date` ASC");

// loop over events
while ($item = $db->fetch())
{
    if (empty($item['edit_date']))
    {
        $item['edit_date'] = date("Y-m-d");
    }
    $output .=
    "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\nSUMMARY:{$item['name']}\r\nUID:{$item['id']}\r\nDTSTART:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($item['date'])) . "\r\nDTEND:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($item['date'])) . "\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($item['edit_date'])) . "\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\n";
}

// close calendar
$output .= "END:VCALENDAR";

echo $output;
```

Comment: Please post your code here for people to read over it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the headers:

```
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=calendar.ical');
```